# Create a dictionary with same key but varied values

Tags: python, grid-search

I'm studying GridSearch method to adjust the parameters of Desicion tree model or random forest model. After reading the example of boston housing price, I found I can't run the code of the example. The following code is the GridSearch code of the example. The problem is `ValueError: Parameter values for parameter (max_depth) need to be a sequence.` I searched certain examples, however, the variable `params` in these examples are almost defined in the same format which can lead to this error. I think the writer want to create a dictionary with key is always is "max_depth" but the value will vary from 1 to 10. I have no clue to solve this problem. Could someone can help me?

```
def fit_model(X, y):
""" Performs grid search over the 'max_depth' parameter for a 
    decision tree regressor trained on the input data [X, y]. """


    # Create cross-validation sets from the training data
    cv_sets = ShuffleSplit(X.shape[0], n_iter = 10, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
    print (cv_sets)
    # Create a decision tree regressor object
    regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor()

    # Create a dictionary for the parameter 'max_depth' with a range from 1 to 10
    params = {'max_depth': range(1,11)}

    # Transform 'performance_metric' into a scoring function using 'make_scorer' 
    scoring_fnc = make_scorer(performance_metric)

    # Create the grid search object
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=regressor, param_grid=params, scoring=scoring_fnc, cv=cv_sets)

    # Fit the grid search object to the data to compute the optimal model
    grid = grid.fit(X, y)

    # Return the optimal model after fitting the data
    return grid.best_estimator_
```

Comment: `range` isn't a sequence in python 3 (not sure of that??). But cheap test: try `params = {'max_depth': list(range(1,11))}`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq

Comment: @StefanPochmann the grid search code is a bit restrictive, see my answer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann the code must be python-2, working on python 3, but no `range` type in python 2, and `range` is list so would have worked.

Comment: How are you importing the GridSearchCV? from the `grid-search` module or the newer `model-selection`? Is the scikit updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My theory is: the `grid-search` module has been designed for python 2 where:

- `range` generates a `list`
- so there ain't no `range` type to check against

So passing a `range` from Python 3 is a cornercase that doesn't work, with a confusing message.

I think I found the reason (and the fix) by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/grid_search.py), around line 348:

```
    check = [isinstance(v, k) for k in (list, tuple, np.ndarray)]
    if True not in check:
        raise ValueError("Parameter values for parameter ({0}) need "
                         "to be a sequence.".format(name))
```

in python 3, `range` [*is* a sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) but since it doesn't generate a `list` anymore, it is not accepted by `grid-search` because the code tests for object types explicity (so the error message is slightly off if you ask me :)). Also, I'm pretty sure that if the code also included `range` in the type test, the rest of the code would work very well, since `range` emulates very closely a `list`, without generating any.

A fix would be to force iteration, for instance like:

```
params = {'max_depth': list(range(1,11))}
```

(`tuple` or `numpy` array would work as well)

To fix `grid-search`, one could do: `for k in (list, tuple, np.ndarray, range)` (but that may break in python 2, and there may exist some python 2/3 compatibility requirements here)

The other fixes would be:

- don't perform any check, let Python decide when using the methods (better ask forgiveness than permission)
- just use `if isinstance(k,(list, tuple, np.ndarray, range)):` as `isinstance` already accepts a `tuple`, no need for the complex construct with the list comprehension generating booleans.

Comment: Wow... that code... could that be any worse? :-) :-(

Comment: machine-learning modules probably aren't the best ones python-wise. They contain a lot of scientific stuff coded by scientists :)

Comment: Wow... someone should submit `if isinstance(v, (list, tuple, np.ndarray, range))` or something there... :)

Comment: @JonClements without breaking python2/python3 compatibility, of course. `range` isn't an object in python 2. The current code has the merit of being compatible with py2 & 3.

Comment: Yeah, but nothing will break... In Python 3 it'll work for the efficient membership test that `range` objects provide... in Python 2.x - that's already covered by checking against `list` and the `isinstance` check against `range` will always be `False`

Comment: @JonClements unless someone passes an integer. that's the point of the check. Sometimes it has to fail. But an extra python 3 + range test could be handy if the other instances fail.

Comment: And how would passing an integer cause it to pass or work unexpectedly?

Comment: I can see that slicing a `range` object could cause issues further down the line by not returning a `list`... but

Comment: the point of the check is to test that a compatible type is passed, to avoid maybe a more cryptic message. So sometimes, I suppose that happens. and in that case, `int` tries to test against `range` type, in python 3 (OK) but fails in python 2.

Comment: maybe it's just that `range` python 3 object wouldn't work, in that case, the message would have to be changed to "needs list/tuple/np.array...", not just "sequence" which is confusing. and slicing a `range` works: `range(1,10)[3:4] => range(4, 5)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what I meant was... if slicing something is expected to return a slice that's a list/tuple etc... you're back to another type check that allow `range`... but anyway... I'll shut up now... I'm not that concerned about it :)

Comment: Hi mate, I'm a newbie and I don't the change of python. Thank you very much for helping solve that problem!